# Iterate through columns in an Excel worksheet

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to achieve this result

```
| method | | passed | | datetime
| method | | passed | | datetime
| method | | passed | | datetime
| method | | passed | | datetime
```

To achieve this, I've currently got a class `XLWriter`

```
class XLWriter:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.workbook = load_workbook(file)
        self.worksheet = self.workbook['Sheet1']
        self.file = file

    def write(self, row):
        index = 0
        try:
            # func name, test passed, date
            values = [[inspect.stack()[0][3]], True, datetime.date]

            columns = [4, 6, 8]

            # 3 writes to perform
            while index < 2:
                cell = self.worksheet.cell(row=row, column=columns[index])
                cell.value = values[index]
                index += 1
        except:
            # function name, declare test failed, date
            values = [[inspect.stack()[0][3]], False, datetime.date]
            columns = [4, 6, 8]
            while index < 2:
                cell = self.worksheet.cell(row=row, column=columns[index])
                cell.value = values[index]
                index += 1

    def save(self):
        self.workbook.save(self.file)
```

When calling this class from `test.py`, as seen below

```
from xlwriter import XLWriter
xl = XLWriter('File.xlsx')

r = self.driver.current_url
self.assertEqual(r, url)
# write to row 14
xl.write(14)
xl.save()
```

I'm met with the following ValueError

```
ValueError: Cannot convert ['write'] to Excel
```

I'm sure it's something small and silly, any help greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Full error stack

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\xlwriter.py", line 21, in write
    cell.value = values[index]
  File "D:\...\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 294, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "D:\...\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 207, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert ['write'] to Excel

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in run
    testMethod()
  File "D:\...\test.py", line 40, in test
    xl.write(14)
  File "D:\...\xlwriter.py", line 29, in write
    cell.value = values[index]
  File "D:\...\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 294, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "D:\...\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 207, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert ['write'] to Excel
```

Comment: can you please share the complete error stack, as after removing some part of code you have shared (call with self.) I am able to write to the file.

Comment: Of course, OP updated @Sach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is failing when you are trying to write a list to cell.

Please update your code to have first element of list "value" as inspect.stack()[0][3] instead of [inspect.stack()[0][3]].

Updated code:

```
class XLWriter:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.workbook = load_workbook(file)
        self.worksheet = self.workbook['Sheet1']
        self.file = file

    def write(self, row):
        index = 0
        try:
            # func name, test passed, date
            values = [inspect.stack()[0][3], True, datetime.date]

            columns = [4, 6, 8]

            # 3 writes to perform
            while index < 2:
                cell = self.worksheet.cell(row=row, column=columns[index])
                cell.value = values[index]
                index += 1
        except:
            # function name, declare test failed, date
            values = [inspect.stack()[0][3], False, datetime.date]
            columns = [4, 6, 8]
            while index < 2:
                cell = self.worksheet.cell(row=row, column=columns[index])
                cell.value = values[index]
                index += 1

    def save(self):
        self.workbook.save(self.file)
```